# MongoDB atlas cost calculation, and how to save cost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongodb-atlas

I am new to MongoDB, and I am trying to develop using MEAN stack. I came across this question when designing APIs. I am also wondering which approach is better to save cost.

1. Fetch the whole document in **one query**, and filter or arrange the data the way I want. This way just needs to call one time.
2. Fetch segment of a document based on the data I needed, will need to call **multiple time** e.g. 10 times.

So, if I choose a plan in MongoDB atlas, how does MongoDB atlas calculate the cost to charge me? Is it by

**how many time you call a query to the database**

or

**How much data is transfer from the database**

Badly need your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have already solved this, but Mongo Atlas works very similar to an on demand host provider, in fact they use AWS, Google Cloud and Azure to host the DB servers you get with them, so they charge an amount per hour according to the size of the server you get, that way you could have the DB active only for half a month and pay for that, or have it for a long time and pay a full month each month.  This link might be useful to select a tier and get a price per hour https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing.  Also, I think there is a free tier, not sure though.

Comment: I don't believe the pricing is on demand, at least for hosting on AWS your paying per hour regardless of usage/traffic.

Comment: They released a new type of cluster: Serverless databases that you pay as you go. [See](https://www.mongodb.com/serverless)